# How can I find properties of conic section (center, vertices, foci, etc.)?

Tags: geometry, algebra

Is there a built-in function that can compute properties of conic section from its equation? For example, provided the equation $\ (x-3)^2/25+(y-4)^2/16=1$ is it possible to find its center, foci, vertices, eccentricity, etc using built-in functions? `PlaneCurveData` is close to what I'm looking for, for an ellipse I need to specify a and b to compute foci or eccentricity:

```
In[117]:= PlaneCurveData["Ellipse", "CartesianEquation"][5, 4][x, y]
Out[117]= x^2/25 + y^2/16 == 1
In[119]:= PlaneCurveData["Ellipse", "Foci"][5, 4]
Out[119]= {{-3, 0}, {3, 0}}
In[126]:= PlaneCurveData["Ellipse", "Eccentricity"][5, 4]
Out[126]= 3/5
```

But I still cannot change the center of the ellipse.

Comment: Somebody once developed [an entire package](http://www.descarta2d.com/BookHTML/Table_of_Contents.html) for this, so the effort needed is nontrivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So `Entity["PlaneCurve", "Ellipse"]` just have two variables

```
Entity["PlaneCurve", "Ellipse"]["Variables"]
```

> [image]

So you cannot adjust the center of the ellipse to solve your question by the `Entity` solution.

```
ResourceFunction["ConicProperties"][x^2/25 + y^2/16 == 1, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Not a "true" answer so much as leveraging the work of others.]

One can use `WolframAlpha` for this.

```
WolframAlpha["properties of x^2/25+y^2/16==1"]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why this code don't work, maybe I have missed something`Entity["PlaneCurve", {EntityProperty["PlaneCurve", 
     "CartesianEquation"] -> 
    Function[{\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}, 
     1/25 (-3 + \[FormalX])^2 + 1/16 (-4 + \[FormalY])^2 == 1]}][
 EntityProperty["PlaneCurve", "Eccentricity"]]`